# Slow pace for TypeWriter

Tags: java, android, textview

I want to do a delay in TypeWriter pace. My default TypeWriter textview pace is with 500ms delay. Suppose if the user types "slow" I want the followed textview TypeWriter at 1000ms delay untill someones types "default". Right now my [code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41715525/typewriter-pace-slow-fast) is only displaying  TextView with 1000ms only ONE  time, after someone types "slow" and then it goes back to default pace. How do I do all the TextView in slow pace after the user types "slow" untill the user types "default" back again.

Code:

```
if (input.getText().toString().contains("slow")){
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Slow pace ON", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            writer_slow.animateText(output.getText().toString());
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about the specific code, but you could have a couple of methods tracking the latest input into the TextView and call on another method (to change the typing speed) whenever a keyword is entered, such as "slow" or "default".

Comment: Thanks, my approach is similiar too..`if (input.getText().toString().contains("slow")){
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Slow pace ON", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                writer_slow.animateText(output.getText().toString());
            }` But with this code, the speed gets slow only once, I want something where the speed remains slow, until the user type "default".